# SQL date not converting in OPENROWSET query but does work as admin user

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select cast('01/05/2014' as date)
```

returns: 2014-05-01

But I have a CSV file with dates (all in May) written in UK format exactly like the above. In fact, I'm using the top 10 records which all have the date: 01/05/2014

My problem is that when I run the below code, the results are all:

```
2014-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-05 | 2014-01-05 | 2014-01-05 | 2014-01-05 | Jan  5 2014 12:00AM  | 05/01/2014
```

This is the code:

```
SELECT top 10
sdispdate
,convert(date, sdispdate, 103)
,cast(sdispdate as date)
,convert(date, cast (sdispdate as date), 103)
,cast(convert(date, sdispdate, 103) as date)
,cast(sdispdate as varchar(50))
,convert(varchar(20), sdispdate, 103)
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\Import;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited(,)', 'SELECT * FROM [MyDataFile.csv]')
```

So my problem is that I cannot convert the already UK date into a UK date. I feel that my issue must have something to do with OPENROWSET - any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I've just run the same query on another SQL 2008R2 server (same as mine) and got the correct result. Both servers show us_english for language and mdy for dateformat when running `DBCC USEROPTIONS`

**UPDATE 2**: I've just run SSMS on my machine as the domain admin and it works... the `DBCC USEROPTIONS` are identical between me and administrator. I am also a sysadmin. My machine is all Australian with no other regional settings. And if I connect to my other server mentioned in my first update as myself or administrator it works. This can only mean that there is a setting unique to my login on this new server only. What else can I check??? I've been on this issue for over 4 hours!!!

Comment: Not helpful at all but in similar situations when it comes time to "GET IT DONE!" i would open the csv in excel and either reformat the date or save as xlsx with typed columns and import that. for other checks two stupid ones: 1.are there quotes or anything around your dates in the CSV..  2. (SO dumb) have you tried going via a datetime?

Comment: sorry also you are accessing the csv file via the ACE Driver.. have you checked the column type of that field as ACE see it?  `foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns) {Console.Write(col.DataType);}` ACE could be shafting you before t-SQL gets near it

Comment: You could use sql import / export tools to do this and probably eliminate the issue too...

Answer (score 0):

Gordatron was right, ACE was shafting me before SQL got it. This meant I couldn't even make the data SUBSTRING etc.

My solution was to simply add a schema.ini to the same folder as the import file. The contents of the are just:

```
[MyDataFile.csv]
DateTimeFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy
```

And that's it.